# Reading strings into individual array/matrix elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file that contains a number of strings, one per line, as below.

```
Happy
Sad
Disgust
Happy
Sad
Etc...
```

I want to be able to read these strings and store them into an array or matrix within Matlab. At the moment the code I have works, but it stores all of the strings into a single array element, like this.

`HappySadDisgustHappySad...`

I want the strings to be stored in their own individual elements.

What changes do I make to this code to make this happen?

```
emotionFile = fopen('emotion_labels_purged.txt','r');
formatSpec = '%s';
sizeEmotionLabels = [1 Inf];
emotionLabels = fscanf(emotionFile,formatSpec,sizeEmotionLabels)
fclose(emotionFile);
```

Comment: Did you try importdata function? It generally reads it into a cell array.

Comment: Okay so I've tried to use importdata, but I need to specify the amount of lines in the file using the headerlinesIn parameter, how do I find the number of lines in the file first instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: I don't think you need to specify it. Is your file too big?

Comment: headerlinesln is to read the header of each column. If you don't specify it, the header names will be automatically detected.

Comment: What is your MATLAB version? If it's sufficiently new (>=R2016b), you can store these strings as "actual" [`string` objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) which are very convenient to work with. Also try [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) instead of `fscanf` - it "_reapplies `formatSpec` throughout the entire file and stops when it cannot match formatSpec to the data_".